# pfSense Killing Uploads to Any Wordpress Site

Tags: networking, firewall, pfsense

I am running a pfSense firewall on version 2.2.6. As far as I remember I have had working rules and have not had any issues uploading to my wordpress sites until this last upgrade. If I try to upload a file to my wordpress site running on a server on LAN4 from my LAN network it always fails. If I switch to LAN2 or LAN3 it works just fine. I have allow rules from LAN to LAN4, LAN4 to LAN, and the same with LAN2 and LAN3, so the rules are the same on each, but only LAN is having this issue. I am stuck at this point. I get a block error in the logs every now and then but not consistently. I have tries many allow rules without success. If it was the server then all LANs should not work, but it is just the one LAN that has an issue uploading to any wordpress site, the upload fails on LAN with a HTTP error.

Comment: What is the HTTP error?

Comment: Do you have Snort or Suricata enabled?